# What is Ellis (enveloping) semigroup of irrational rotation of unit circle?

Tags: analysis, dynamical-systems, topological-dynamics

Ellis semigroup is defined for cascade (X,f), where X is topological space and f is a homeomorphism, is defined as pointwise closure of set {f^n:n in Z}.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is about topological dynamical systems.  If (X,f) is a pair, where f:X->X is a homeomorphism and X is a topological space, then ellis semigroup is defined as closure of {f^n : n belongs to integers}, f^n denote fofofof.. n times.

Comment: SO, my question is according to this definition if I consider f as irrational rotation on X ,which is unit circle, then what will be it's ellis semigroup?